# C++ cannot access element of vector of abstract class?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, vector, polymorphism, abstract-class

I have 2 simple C++ headers implemented as in the following:

Attribute.h

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class IAttribute
{
    virtual string getName(){};
};

class StringAttribute : public IAttribute
{
private:
    string name = "";
    string value = "";

public:
    StringAttribute(string name, string value)
    {
        this->name = name;
        this->value = value;
    }
    string getName()
    {
        return this->name;
    }
    string getStrValue()
    {
        return value;
    }
    void setValue(string value)
    {
        this->value = value;
    }
};
```

tableRow.h

```
#include "attribute.h"
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
class TableRow
{
private:
    vector<IAttribute *> attributeList;
    int rowId;

public:
    TableRow(int rowId)
    {
        this->rowId = rowId;
    }

    void addStrAttribute(string name, string value)
    {    
        attributeList.push_back(new StringAttribute(name, value));
    }
    StringAttribute getStrAtt(string name)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < (int)attributeList.size(); i++)
        {
            if (attributeList[i]->)//couldn't access the methods of StringAttributeImp
            {

            }
        }
    }
};
```

As in the comment of tableRow header above, I couldn't access the methods and properties of the Implementation class. What is wrong?

Comment: Even if you make the getName() public, the code would not be compiled. For eg., getName() is not abstract and it has implementation which does not return the string. The IAttribute does not have virtual destructor. Watch out for these problems in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `getName` function is `private` in the `IAttribute` class.  So of course you're not able to access it.

Comment: Now I can access the getName method, but is there anyway to access methods in StringAttribute without listing it in the IAttribute abstract class?

Comment: You can use `dynamic_cast` to check if the `IAttribute*` pointer you retrieve from the `vector` is pointing at a `StringAttribute` object. If so, you will have the `StringAttribute*` pointer needed to access its members.

Comment: @AbdulwadoudTah: No. What do you think is the whole point of having `IAttribute`? It's to list common members. So go ahead and do that now.

Answer (score 1):

You should change the **getName** function to **public**;  or use **friend** class.